# Scala installation in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

I Use Eclipse From a Long Time Ago.But Now I Need Scala To Install In My Eclipse IDE so I Follow That step IN Eclipse IDE-

1-tap on help button.

2- tap on Intall New Software.

3- tap on add button.

4-Set Name as "Scala" and link "http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e47/scala212/stable/site"

5- And Then Select All library of Scala to Install and Click on next.

6- Then An Error occur that is show in image.Error is

"Installing software Has Encountered a Problem

an error occurred while collecting items to be intalled."

Comment: The Scala plugin for eclipse is deprecated. Even if you manage to install it, it will be very slow and will crash most of the time. I would recommend you to use either **IntellIJ** if you like IDEs, or some text editor with **metals**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez i only want to use scala with java library and that is why i wanna install it in eclipse..

Comment: So what? All the other IDEs or text editors I mentioned also understand **Java**. In any case, if you only want to use Java libraries, what is the point of using **Scala**? Why not not just using **Java** or maybe **Kotlin**?

Comment: yes @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez you are right,but my teacher force me to install Scala in eclipse and that is why i asked here to resolve my issue...

Comment: Then tell you professor to either improve their installation guidelines or upgrade to a newer editor, If you wan yo use it on eclipse, then you would need to use older scala versions.

Comment: exactly,,i will.